# iOS applications Localization.strings file name change

Tags: ios, string, localization

IOS application provide the support of localization through the Localizable.strings file. If I want to change the file name for some obvious reasons where would I have to put that reference.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Could you let us know what is the obvious reasons?

Comment: i have two projects A, B. In A there is a folder name B. I work the project B separately and add all the files to the Project A. As in project A there is already a file named Localizable.strings so i can not use Localizable.stringss in B also. that is the reason

Comment: I don't really get it ;) do you want A or B or do you want to merge A and B ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How iOS localization works:

As you would already know, iOS provides a nice API for getting localized string as following.

```
NSString *stringValue = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key
                                                                   value:@""
                                                                   table:nil];
```

And it also provides a macro for quick access as:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

iOS, by default, looks for strings in **Localizable.strings** file. However, we can also provide a custom file for iOS to look for strings into. And this is where things get interesting.

To provide a custom file, we can use the API as mentioned above in following manner.

```
NSString *localizedString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key
                                                                   value:@""
                                                                   table:@"AnotherLocalizableStringsFile"];
```

The **table** parameter takes a string argument **AnotherLocalizableStringsFile** which is the file containing the strings.

Another interesting parameter is the **value** parameter that takes in a string that should be returned in case no string is found matching the given key.

So following piece of code would return **Invalid Key** assuming the provided key **does not** exist in the file.

```
NSString *stringValue = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:@"Wrong_key_passed"
                                                                   value:@"Invalid Key"
                                                                   table:@"TargetLocalizable"];
```

### The solution:

By using the combination of these two interesting parameters, we can devise a method to suit our requirements. We will ask iOS to look for strings specific to target in target specific strings file and fall back to **Localizablestrings** file when it comes to loading generic strings common to all targets.

Here’s how the piece of code looks like.

```
NSString *stringValue = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:@"Key"
                                                                   value:NSLocalizedString(@"Key", nil)
                                                                   table:@"TargetLocalizable"];
```

So, iOS looks for the string first in the given **TargetLocalizable**.strings file. If it doesn’t find it there, it would search in the base **Localizable**.strings file.

So all I had to do was to place all the strings common to all targets in **Localizable**.strings file and put the additional and overridden strings specific to the target in **TargetLocalizable**.strings file.

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. You save my day.

Comment: I found another way NSString *string = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Key", @"TableName", @"Default Text");

Answer (score 0):

The name is 'fixed' - a localizable is named Localizable. you can only decide to not use NSBundle localization and roll your own stuff